# Have certain limit and have to decide which statements are certainly correct

Tags: limits, functions

I have this limit

[image]

And have to decide which statements are certainly true.

[image]

I am sure that statement #5 is correct ,because 1 divided by minus infinity is zero. And it also says that 1 divided by minus infinity is not minus infinity and thus #6 is incorrect. So I have clue about 2 from 8 so far. Will you help me with others? thx a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Am I right now?

1. should be -infinity
2. should be -infinity
3. should be +infinity
4. should be -infinity
5. OK
6. should be 0
7. OK
8. should be + infinity

Comment: 4 is false. We have $f(x^2)\to-\infty $.

Comment: Yea, now I see, if we have f(x)=-x,then f(x^2)=-(x)^2, so it is still minus infinity, thanks a lot! And want to ask you 5 and 7 are correct and every other is false, is that so? :)

Comment: OK, I have edited my answers, is this correct?

Comment: Looks ok now. +1

Comment: Passed, thanks a lot, sir. :)

Comment: Just noted now that your 3) is not correct. The information in question is not sufficient to conclude anything about $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(1-x)$ and hence you can't say that it is $+\infty $.

Comment: I told myself that if lim(x) is -infinity, then lim(1-x) should be +infinity. There is also certain limit at the beginning of my question from which all statements are created.

Comment: You can't chose any specific example function $f$ like $f(x) =-x$ to draw your conclusions. The conclusions in each of the above options are based on limit laws (change of variables / substitution in limits).